# Ошибка при передаче ссылки на метод

Tags: c++

Всех приветствую.

Имеется класс:

```
Joystick.h

struct JOYSTICK_MESSAGE
{
    int pressedButtonID;
    int state;
};


class Joystick  
{
    public:
        JOYSTICK_MESSAGE* getState();

        void initInterrupt();

        ~Joystick(){
            delete this->m_message;
        }

    private:
        void onButtonPressed();
        JOYSTICK_MESSAGE* m_message = new JOYSTICK_MESSAGE();
        int lastButtonID = -1;
        int startTouchTime = 0;
        bool buttonState = false;
};
```

И

```
Joystick.cpp
.....
void Joystick::initInterrupt() 
{
    attachInterrupt(1, onButtonPressed, LOW);
}

void Joystick::onButtonPressed() 
{
    
}
```

В функции   attachInterrupt(1, onButtonPressed, LOW); (ардуиновская)

возникает ошибка:

> void Joystick::onButtonPressed() argument of type "void
> (Joystick::*)()" is incompatible with parameter of type "void (*)()

что с этим можно сделать?

Пробовал так:

```
void Joystick::initInterrupt() 
{
    attachInterrupt(1, onButtonPressed, LOW);
}

void onButtonPressed() 
{
    // this 
}
```

Но тогда отсутствует доступ к this в функции onButtonPressed()

> 'this' may only be used inside a nonstatic member functionC

Comment: потому что attachInterrupt принимает указатель на функцию, а Вы пытаетесь подсунуть указатель на функцию-член класса (обозвав ее "методом").

Comment: @KoVadim, а что с этим можно сделать? :\

Comment: передать туда функцию с подходящей сигнатурой - в данном случае без параметров и возвращающую void

Comment: @KoVadim, можете, пожалуйста, набросать пример?

Comment: второй пример похож на правду, но this там не будет.